# NodeJS ExpressJS process array in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an array of ids and I need to send a request to another microservice for each id and it takes a lot of time.
Is it possible to do it in parallel? Code looks like that

```
const ids = [1,2,3,4]
const objects = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => this._getData(id)))
```

Comment: Promise.all waits for all to resolve so its no longer *parallel* for whatever consumes the objects, if your passing to res, then it would be less coupling if the clientside code did the calls to single items, then it can be reactive to each one coming in, additionally _getData should support passing an array then it sends the array to the query and the db/api layer fetch all items at once instead of fetching one at a time

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have to connect with external api and I can't change it

Answer (score -1):

```
app.param('user', function (req, res, next, id) {
  // try to get the user details from the User model and attach it to the request object
  User.find(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else if (user) {
      req.user = user
      next()
    } else {
      next(new Error('failed to load user'))
    }
  })
})
```